# Can I clone a VM from one cluster to another using pyvmomi?

Tags: python, vmware

We have two VMware datacenters, both attached to our vCenter server. All VMware 5.5. I have a VM (not template) that I am tying to clone in an automated way using [pyvmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi). The script works fine if I specify that I want the VM cloned to a host in the same datacenter as the source VM. However, if I specify a host in the other datacenter, the clone fails with a vmodl error:

A specified parameter was not correct.

As far as I have been able to tell, I am setting everything right in the RelocateSpec and CloneSpec, as well as the actual CloneVM_Task call. Any pointers in the right direction would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Here's the script:

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
from pyVmomi import vim, vmodl
import atexit
import sys
import time
import pprint
#import pudb

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

def WaitForTasks(tasks, si):
    global pp
    """
    Given the service instance si and tasks, it returns after all the
    tasks are complete
    """
    pc = si.content.propertyCollector
    task_result = None
    taskList = [str(task) for task in tasks]

    # Create filter
    objSpecs = [vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.ObjectSpec(obj=task) for task in tasks]
    propSpec = vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.PropertySpec(type=vim.Task, pathSet=[], all=True)
    filterSpec = vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.FilterSpec()
    filterSpec.objectSet = objSpecs
    filterSpec.propSet = [propSpec]
    filter = pc.CreateFilter(filterSpec, True)

    try:
        version, state = None, None

        # Loop looking for updates till the state moves to a completed state.
        while len(taskList):
            update = pc.WaitForUpdates(version)
            for filterSet in update.filterSet:
                for objSet in filterSet.objectSet:
                    task = objSet.obj
                    for change in objSet.changeSet:
                        if change.name == 'info':
                            state = change.val.state
                        elif change.name == 'info.state':
                            state = change.val
                        else:
                            continue

                        if not str(task) in taskList:
                            continue

                        if state == vim.TaskInfo.State.success:
                            #save info
                            task_result = task.info.result

                            # Remove task from taskList
                            taskList.remove(str(task))
                        elif state == vim.TaskInfo.State.error:
                            raise task.info.error
            # Move to next version
            version = update.version
    except Exception, e:
        print "Caught Exception in WaitForTasks : " + pp.pprint(e)
    finally:
        if filter:
            filter.Destroy()

    return task_result



"""
 Get the vsphere object associated with a given text name
"""
def GetObject(content, vimtype, name):
    obj = None
    container = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, vimtype, True)
    for c in container.view:
        if c.name == name:
            obj = c
            break
    return obj 


def WaitForIP(target_machine):
    while target_machine.guest.ipAddress == None:
        print "Waiting for IP to be visible..."
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    global pp

    try:
        si = None
        server = 'vcenter'

        try:
            si = SmartConnect(host=server, user='adminuser', pwd='password', port=443)
        except IOError, e:
            pass
        if not si:
            print "Could not connect to vCenter using specified username and password"
            return -1

        atexit.register(Disconnect, si)

        # Get references to the needed objects
        content = si.content
        source_machine = GetObject(content,[vim.VirtualMachine],'ubuntu14.04')
        destination_host = GetObject(content, [vim.HostSystem], 'vmhostname')

        if "bos" in destination_host.name:
            dsname = 'bosdatastore'
            dcname = 'Boston'
        else:
            dsname = 'reddatastore'
            dcname = 'Redmond'

        # Configure where the new machine is to be located
        rs = vim.VirtualMachineRelocateSpec()
        cs = vim.VirtualMachineCloneSpec()
        dc = GetObject(content, [vim.Datacenter], dsname)
        target_folder = dc.vmFolder
        rs.host = destination_host
        cs.location = rs
        cs.powerOn = False

        # Clone it
        tasks = [source_machine.CloneVM_Task(target_folder, 'newmachine', cs)]
        print "Clone initiated..."
        sys.stdout.flush()
        target_machine = WaitForTasks(tasks, si)
        print("Virtual Machine %s has been cloned successfully" % "newmachine")

        # update NIC settings if needed
        for dev in target_machine.config.hardware.device:
            if dev.deviceInfo.label == 'Network adapter 1':
                nic = dev
                break

        if nic.backing.deviceName != 'vlan1':
            net = GetObject(content,[vim.Network],'vlan2')
            vds = vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec()
            nic.backing.deviceName = 'vlan2'
            nic.backing.network = net
            nic.deviceInfo.summary = 'vlan2'
            vds.device = nic
            vds.operation = vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec.Operation.edit
            vmcs = vim.vm.ConfigSpec()
            vmcs.deviceChange = [vds]
            tasks = [target_machine.ReconfigVM_Task(vmcs)]
            print "Network change started..."
            sys.stdout.flush()
            WaitForTasks(tasks,si)
            print "Network update complete."

        # Power the machine on
        tasks = [target_machine.PowerOnVM_Task()]
        print "New machine is starting..."
        sys.stdout.flush()
        WaitForTasks(tasks,si)

        # Wait for target to have IP so we can save it
        WaitForIP(target_machine)

    except vmodl.MethodFault, e:
        print "Caught vmodl fault in main : " + pp.pprint(e)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Caught Exception in main : " + pp.pprint(e)

    print "Done."

# Start program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You seem to have missed closing the quote after `adminuser` username on this line `si = SmartConnect(host=server, user='adminuser, pwd='password', port=443)`

Comment: Thanks. That was an edit error when I sanitized the script.

Answer (score 0):

`CloneSpec` takes a parameter `RelocateSpec` . So basically you are cloning a vm/template and migrating(I don't know it is hot or cold) it to a different host/cluster.

After seeing your question the first thing I googled is, "vMotion is possible across Datacenters or not". I get the answer that, "vMotion is not possible across datacenters but a cold migration is possible"

Now as I said that I don't know `RelocateSpec` use vMotion or not. But looks like it is not possible even if all the hosts of each datacenter shares a common repo.

Have a look at this article [Cloning VM from one datacenter to another datacenter](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-24693) from Vmware. It basically clones and exports it as ovf and then imports the ovf in the target datacenter.